# React use client directive with parceljs bundler

Tags: reactjs, monorepo, parceljs, turborepo

`Parceljs` is unable to deal with `"use client"` directive. I've a monorepo (pnpm workspaces + turborepo). `apps/web` is dependent on `pkgs/ui` that includes UI components. Since components are all client side and need to access client side APIs, I need to add `"use client"` directive in my ui bundle file. Parcel bundler is misplacing the directive in output bundles, though the source file `pkgs/ui/src/index.ts` has used the directive at the top. Bundle has the directive somewhere at the bottom.

How I may resolve this issue with minimal work (desireably if parcel could deal it on its side)?

Key considerations is dev / watch mode. When working in development mode with `turbo dev` that will call all workspaces (`apps/web pkgs/lib pkgs/ui`) dev scripts - solution should work seamlessly when any of these gets rebuilt.

---

###### Source

`pkgs/ui/src/index.ts`

```
"use client"

export * from './button'
// ...
// ...
// ...
```

###### Bundle

`pkgs/ui/dist/module.js`

```js
var $k6BiE$reactjsxdevruntime = require("react/jsx-dev-runtime");
var $k6BiE$ar124officialwdlib = require("@ar124officialwd/lib");
var $k6BiE$react = require("react");

// ...
// ...
// ...

"use client";
$parcel$exportWildcard(module.exports, $8aff37b36b5eccbe$exports);


//# sourceMappingURL=module.js.map
```

###### Desired Bundle

`pkgs/ui/dist/module.js`

```js
"use client";
var $k6BiE$reactjsxdevruntime = require("react/jsx-dev-runtime");
var $k6BiE$ar124officialwdlib = require("@ar124officialwd/lib");
var $k6BiE$react = require("react");

// ...
// ...
// ...

$parcel$exportWildcard(module.exports, $8aff37b36b5eccbe$exports);


//# sourceMappingURL=module.js.map
```

Answer (score 0):

> (desirably if parcel could deal it on its side)?

That would mean a [Parcel plugin](https://parceljs.org/features/plugins/), to modify (["Transformer" plugin](https://parceljs.org/features/plugins/#transformers)) the bundle process and make sure `"use client"` stays at the top of the bundle file.

Create a file for the custom Parcel plugin, e.g., `parcel-plugin-client-directive.js`.

```js
const { Transformer } = require('@parcel/plugin');

module.exports = new Transformer({
    async transform({ asset }) {
    let code = await asset.getCode();
    if (code.includes('"use client";')) {
        code = '"use client";\n' + code.replace('"use client";', '');
    }
    asset.setCode(code);
    return [asset];
    },
});
```

Add this plugin to your `package.json`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "parcel-plugin-client-directive": "file:./path/to/parcel-plugin-client-directive.js"
}
```

[Parcel’s watch mode](https://parceljs.org/features/development/#hot-reloading), which is active during development, automatically rebuilds your files when changes are detected. The custom plugin will be invoked on each rebuild, making sure that the `"use client"` directive is correctly placed every time.

Once the plugin is part of your Parcel configuration, no extra steps are required from your side when working in dev/watch mode.